# Spring Data CosmosDB multi tenant CosmosDB Configuration

Tags: java, azure, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using CosmosDB in a multi-tenant application. Have a separate database for each tenant and the Collections for each tenant are in their own database.

Given that my application has to handle multiple tenants, I cannot have a single configuration for my repositories which has a pre-defined database. The database has to be dynamically configured based on the request context (tenant). How is it possible to achieve such a setup with Spring Data CosmosDB?

Here's how the Repository Configuration is setup. As you can see, this has the database fixed through the application properties. In a real world scenario, the application has requests coming from different tenants; so will have to use different databases

```
@Configuration
@EnableCosmosRepositories
@Slf4j
public class UserRepositoryConfiguration extends AbstractCosmosConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private CosmosDBProperties properties;

  private CosmosKeyCredential cosmosKeyCredential;

      @Bean
      @Primary
      public CosmosDBConfig cosmosDbConfig() {
        this.cosmosKeyCredential = new CosmosKeyCredential(properties.getKey());
        CosmosDBConfig cosmosDBConfig = CosmosDBConfig.builder(properties.getUri(), cosmosKeyCredential,
            properties.getDatabase()).build();
        cosmosDBConfig.setPopulateQueryMetrics(properties.isPopulateQueryMetrics());
        cosmosDBConfig.setResponseDiagnosticsProcessor(new ResponseDiagnosticsProcessorImplementation());
        return cosmosDBConfig;
      }

      public void switchToPrimaryKey() {
        this.cosmosKeyCredential.key(properties.getKey());
      }

      public void switchKey(String key) {
        this.cosmosKeyCredential.key(key);
      }

      private static class ResponseDiagnosticsProcessorImplementation implements ResponseDiagnosticsProcessor {

        @Override
        public void processResponseDiagnostics(@Nullable ResponseDiagnostics responseDiagnostics) {
          log.info("Response Diagnostics {}", responseDiagnostics);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting my .net code here for reference, it will help you to write your spring code.

You have to create one database account and need keys (`DatabaseEndPoint` & `DatabaseKey`). Then everthing you can create dynamically i.e database, collection etc. based on your tenant.

In .net, I use dependency injection to inject `IDocumentClient`. below is my configuration

```
string databaseEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseEndPoint"]; //Get from config file
string databaseKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseKey"];//Get from config file
services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(new DocumentClient(new System.Uri(databaseEndPoint), databaseKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),//Groupasset sync has some timeout issue with large payload
                // Customize retry options for Throttled requests
                RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
                {
                    MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 5,
                    MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60
                }
            }
        ));
```

**BaseDAO/BaseRepository**

```
public abstract class BaseDao : IBaseDao
{
    protected readonly IDocumentClient client;

    protected BaseDao(IDocumentClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create Document in Database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="databaseId">database name</param>
    /// <param name="collectionId">collection name</param>
    /// <param name="document">document object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual async Task<string> CreateAsync(string databaseId, string collectionId, JObject document)
    {
        Document response = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId), document);
        return response.Id;
    }
}
```

Create DAO/Repository class and inherit from base DAO.

In my scenario, we are creating database based on `tenant` name i.e. google, microsoft etc. based on user (bill@microsoft.com) all query execute under one (microsoft) database.

Comment: Hi Pankaj. I am actually using the spring-data-cosmosdb library. If I am directly using the DocumentClient, it would have been possible to implement some form of multi-tenancy;

Answer (score 0):

From version **3.33.0** of the Spring Data Client Library for Azure Cosmos DB, you can now make your Spring Data Repository code dynamically reference and/or create different databases or containers in Azure Cosmos DB for each tenant, from the same application instance and the same client. To achieve this at database level, create a class which extends CosmosFactory:

```
public class MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory extends CosmosFactory {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory .class);
    private CosmosAsyncClient client;
    public String tenantId;

    public MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory (CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient, String databaseName) {
        super(cosmosAsyncClient, databaseName);
        this.client = cosmosAsyncClient;
        this.tenantId = databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        //have some logic here that will determine the tenant id in the current thread
        //so you can set this.tenantId to be the current tenant
        return this.tenantId;
    }
}
```

Then, in your configuration class, add your new MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory class as a bean:

```
@Bean 
 public MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory cosmosFactory(CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient) {
    return new MultiTenantDBCosmosFactory (cosmosAsyncClient, getDatabaseName());
 }
```

The overridden `getDatabaseName()` will them be invoked polymorphically by every CRUD method you call on Spring Data `Repository`, so you will need to add some logic that will determine the tenant id in the current thread, and set that value to be returned. To do the same at container level instead, you would just override the `overrideContainerName()` method in CosmosFactory instead, and add similar logic.

I've written a blog, which goes into more detail on this, and has links to some extended samples, including how to capture request context (tenant) using `WebRequestInterceptor`. You can find the blog [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/building-multi-tenant-java-apps-using-spring-data-and-azure-cosmos-db/).